# How do i achieve "read -i" in a different way?

Tags: bash, sh, busybox

I Have been looking on the internet but without finding a solution (hard to know what to serach for). I want a way to show "current value" on an input. Similar to what `read -e -p "something: " -i "this" $variable` does but in Busybox sh. As that option only became available in Bash4 which is not default. I will have to solve it another way. Not sure if this is possible..

```
read -p "Select by entering an number: " ANS
    case $ANS in
        1 ) ANS="%R | %a %d %b" ;;
        2 ) ANS="%R, %a %d %b" ;;
        3 ) read -p "Enter a custom string (ex. %R): " ANS ;;
        4 ) ANS="%R" ;;
        * ) read -p "Just answer with a number between 1 to 4. Aborting!" end; exit 0 ;;
    esac
```

What i want is that case #3 will show the current value of the file. Ex. If the file has %R as current value. Then that is what i want it to show on input for user to interactively change it.

Comment: please edit your question above to show (simple) example input and output. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter As my question is about that.. i do not see how that would be possible. Right now my string is `read -p "something" $variable` as that is the only supported way.

Comment: suit yourself, you're asking us to visualize your problem. That leaves a lot of room for error. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter If you don't know what a command does you do not need to comment. Even worse vote down. Read up on it instead. I posted a snippet of the code i use but it will not explain more than what i already wrote before. You could even have used the command in your terminal if it uses bash4 and seen what it did.

Answer (score 0):

Until you can give us examples of what you want the programme to take as an 'input' and then give as an 'output', I suggest you read [TLPD's section](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html) on 'read'

Comment: I asked for another way to do a command if possible.. so input/output is of little value in this case. Just wanted to see if someone knew another way..

Comment: As far as I'm aware, `read` is the only input bash scripts can take without some convoluted method of writing to file then reading that file.

The example in the question _really_ helps now. Thanks.